# For production dApps, what kind of sync should be done on server node?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, fast-sync, server-side

I plan to use web3 server side using NodeJs with geth. For production usage, should I do a `full` sync or `fast` sync is enough?

Also, how much space do I need to store the blockchain data for each of these sync types as on today?

Answer (score 1):

`Fast` synchronization is usually OK, you download both blocks and states. However, using `full` synchronization you only download the blocks, and compute the states yourself. It takes MUCH more time, but you are sure the states are valid. If you don't mind waiting it's always a plus to do it `full`, but for most cases `fast` suffices.

Concerning the required size, you can take a look at [this chart](https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault), which shows it very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for 'fast' sync and it will require about 21gb of space.

Basically 'light' sync is for testing and development purpose.